# Split results in different rows mysql query

Tags: mysql

I created this table (results) in my sql database (test)

```
CREATE DATABASE `test`; 
USE `test`;
CREATE TABLE `results` (
`number` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_machine` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` float NOT NULL,
`datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`number`),
UNIQUE KEY `indice_UNIQUE` (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

I have the following results

```
8, 22.22, 42.56, 8.95, 3.64
```

I would like to save my data in my table in this way:

```
Number  id_machine   value      datetime  
 101         8       22.22     2013-06-05 14:03:00
 102         8       42.56     2013-06-05 14:03:00
 103         8        8.95     2013-06-05 14:03:00
 104         8        3.64     2013-06-05 14:03:00
```

Is there any easy way to do this query?

Something like

```
char query[]="INSERT INTO results(`id_machine`,`value`) VALUES(......)";
```

Comment: Is the same question with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938281/how-to-separate-result-values-in-different-rows-using-mysql-query but a simple version. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, perhaps?

```
insert into `results` (`id_machine`, `value`, `datetime`)
values (8, 22.22, '2013-06-05 14:03:00'),
       (8, 42.56, '2013-06-05 14:03:00'), 
       (8, 8.95,  '2013-06-05 14:03:00'),
       (8, 3.64, '2013-06-05 14:03:00');
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8fa74/1).